# K8s default-container annotation not working

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE cluster and some pods running on a spot node.

For a pod with 2 containers, `foo` and `bar` and 1 initContainer, `baz` I added `kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container: "foo"`.

Expected behaviour is when we do `kubectl exec` without specifying the `-c` flag, it should get a shell inside `foo` but it's trying to get the shell inside `baz`

Is there a way to debug/troubleshoot?

Comment: Check which version of kubectl you are using.

Comment: ```
Client Version: v1.24.0
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.21.11-gke.1100
```

Comment: @mayankb were you able to find the answer ?